# Issue when setting a default path in BASH

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I am developing a simple BASH script to watch a given compass project. My script is shown below.

I would like to allow a user to optionally enter a custom path or use the default `http_path` value. I'm not sure how to set the `path` variable equal to the `http_path` variable where my default Apache directory is located using my current script. If any one has better suggestions and/or resources for learning how to write BASH scripts, please share!

**Note:** I have searched this site, Google, and stackoverflow for an answer. If you find one with a solution to my issue, please let me know!

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will watch a given compass project
http_path=/var/www/

echo -n "Enter in a new path and press. To use the default path $http_path press [ENTER] twice"

while read path; do
    if [ -z "${path}" ]; then
        clear  
        # these two lines enable the script to work if I do not
        # I do not prompt for default path. It's been tested and works
        # echo "That was empty, do it again!"
        # echo -n "Enter in a compass project directory and press [ENTER]"
        echo "Are you sure you would like to use the default path? Press [ENTER] to continue..."
        $path=$http_path
    else
        echo "Checking now..."
        break
    fi
done

echo -n "Enter in a project to watch and prss [ENTER]"

while read project; do
    if [ -z "${project}" ]; then
        clear  
        echo "That was empty, do it again!"
        echo -n "Enter in a compass project name and press [ENTER]"
    else
        echo "Checking now..."
        break
    fi
done

echo "Watching" $project "project in directory" $path
echo "To exit project press Command/Control + C"

cd $path
compass watch $project
```

See problem solution [here](http://pastebin.com/1expxwpF)

Comment: Are you referring to DocumentRoot here?

Comment: To the document root of my apache server. /var/www/ is where all of my php scripts are located

Comment: I would grep for it in the httpd_conf and set it automatically.

Comment: Awesome idea but it differs from dirstro to distro. Some it's in /etc/apache2 and for others it might be in /etc/httpd, any way to dynamically figure out where the httpd.conf or apache2.conf file might be?

Comment: @djthoms, who says it has to be dynamical? Could edit the script when installing.

Comment: For bash scripting, a tutorial is http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ ("abs" is "advanced bash scripting", if you are wondering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning a value to `path`, leave off the leading `$` sign in the first while loop.

You only need to do: `path=$http_path`.

**Edit**

I only realized after I posted that you also want resources to learn bash. I personally found [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) to be useful. It is a bit dated if I remember correctly, but it is more than sufficient. Also `#bash` on Freenode is a great place. They're not always the friendliest but they are definitely extraordinarily knowledgable.

Also, never be afraid to test out something on the command-line. That's your interactive interpreter (if you've done any ruby or python programming).

**Edit 2**

The actual problem was that after hitting enter the user wouldn't exit the loop so the code needed to be changed to:

```
while read path; do
    if [ -z "${path}" ]; then
        clear
        echo "Are you sure you would like to ..."
        read prompt
        if [ -n "${prompt}" ] ; then
            continue
        fi
        path=$http_path
        break
    else
        # etc.
    fi
done
```

Comment: Alright, good to know! It seems it is getting stuck at that point where the user would press enter again to use the default path. I can press enter for days and nothing happens.

Comment: Oh I entirely missed that. You're doing an echo without a subsequent read. You're not checking their input and as such the while loop is just running constantly. You need to read and break after that echo.

Comment: The addition of the break worked wonderfully! I have been testing I just got stuck on that one part. I'm mainly a PHP developer but I have experience in Python and Java.

Comment: @djthoms you might want to make sure that what you read in after that echo is of zero-length. If it isn't, you might want to continue to prompt them for input. Check my edited answer. Cheers!

Comment: Also you might want to check if the path they're providing actually exists in advance, e.g., `if ! [ -d "${path}" ] ; echo "ERROR: Path does not exist" ; fi`